# File processing with different record layouts

Tags: python

Could you please help to know how to perform file processing in python code which has different layout for each record and there are 3 types of record layouts.

Field-1 and 2 will be constant and can be used as record identifier and record fields are separated by ',' delimiter -

Record-Type Record structure

```
R1          ex - Id,Name1,Name2,Name3,Address{},Phones{}
R2          ex - Id,Year,Make,Model,Length
R3          ex - Id,Transactions{Trxn1,Trnx2,Trnx3,Trnx4}
R2          ex - Id,Name1,Name2,Name3,Address{},Phones{}
R2          ex - Id,Year,Make,Model,Length
R1          ex - Id,Transactions{Trxn1,Trnx2,Trnx3,Trnx4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question's awfully vague, but the following might get you started:

You can read each line of the file in as a string in a `for` loop and then use `fields = line.split(',')` to break it up into a variable-length list of field values. Following that you can use the values of `fields[0]` and `fields[1]` to identify which type record you're dealing with and process the remaining field values as needed.

Here's some code showing how the processing of lines read from the file might be done:

```
H2 = ['Id', 'Year', 'Make', 'Model', 'Length']

line = 'B42,2015,Ford,F-150,243.7'

fields = line.split(',')
record_id = fields[0][0]

if record_id == 'A':
    record = dict(zip(H1, fields))
    print('{Id}, {Name1}, {Name2}, {Name3}, {Address}, {Phones}'.format(**record))
elif record_id == 'B':
    record = dict(zip(H2, fields))
    print('{Id}, {Year}, {Make}, {Model}, {Length}'.format(**record))
elif record_id == 'C':
    pass  # ... etc
```

Output:

```
B42, 2015, Ford, F-150, 243.7
```

Comment: Thanks martineau, The { and } indicates an array or list of items.

Comment: Well, that sounds like they're going to require some special handling, but again you have provided enough information for any one to help you. Suggest you write some code based on my outline and if you get stuck, ask another question here.

Comment: Can you please help on below - How do we read  a file which contains 5 different layout/structure records and identity structure/layout based on first field and apply particular heading or read it with that heading

Comment: Where do the IDs and record layouts (headings/field_names) come from?

Comment: I need to define 5 different headings (H1, H2, H3, ..) in program and based on first character (A, B, C, ...) I have to apply Heading H1 for A type record or read file record with  H1 format heading... and so on